# Is it possible to do redirects in Shopify with wildcards?

Tags: shopify, liquid

We want to be able to do something like allow a user to type "website.com/0431", where 0431 corresponds to a specific products manual and redirects to it. Is this possible with Shopify?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can set up redirects in Shopify. There is a redirect setup mechanism built right into the Admin. Online Store -> Navigation -> URL Redirects.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to do wildcard redirects in Shopify Admin.
Not with the built in redirects tool.
There are Shopify apps for that. I tried a couple of the top hits but there are no  free ones.

From the Shopify help center:

> If you want to create a lot of redirects, you can simplify this process using an [app](https://apps.shopify.com/search?q=redirects).

Source:
[Redirects documentation at Shopify help center](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/menus-and-links/url-redirect#create-a-url-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentally created markets subfolder URLs then there are a bunch of indexed /en-**/ URLs. All those URLs will become 404 when you remove their market.

Here are 2 ways to fix it:

1/ Purchase Cloudflare Enterprise plan and active O2O, then use page rule to redirect your URLs.

OR

2/ Put this in your `main-404.liquid` (if you only want to fix 404 URLs) or `header.liquid`:

```
<script>
// Get the current path from the window location
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

// Use a regular expression to match the pattern and extract the suffix
const match = currentPath.match(/^\/en-(\w{2})(?:\/(.*))?$/);

// If there's a match and the suffix is available, redirect to the extracted suffix
// Otherwise, if there's a match but no suffix, redirect to the homepage
if (match) {
    window.location.pathname = match[2] ? `/${match[2]}` : '/';
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Is this sufficient for redirection or do I need to set up the redirection rules as well using an app since Shopify doesn't support wildcard redirection?

Comment: There is no need to set any redirection rule, the code will redirect all `/en-**/` URLs to corresponding main market URLs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not using it for Markets specifically, but a migrated WordPress website to Shopify. While I have added the redirects for exact urls, for paginated urls, do I need to add the redirection rules using an app? Or is the above code sufficient? For now I have used the above code to redirect to homepage if the link is not found and returns 404. But will it affect Google rankings?

Comment: @input please don't use the code when you don't understand how it will affect your store. In your case please hire a professional.

Comment: thanks for your help. We resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While there are redirect capabilities in Shopify, you currently cannot do wildcard redirects (as of Mar 2018)

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2022, you can indeed set up wildcard redirects in your Shopify store at the `{your-shop}.myshopify.com/admin/redirects` (or under Online Store > Navigation > View URL redirects).

The syntax for **Redirect from**: `/support/*`

The syntax for **Redirect to**: `https://support.domain.com/global-search/*`

Comment: Tested and does not work as of Oct 2022, there is no mention of this in Shopify's official docs https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/menus-and-links/url-redirect#create-a-url-redirect